# How to use two firebase database in angular application

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a environment variable like this

```
 export const environment = {   
production: false,
   firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: '',
        authDomain: '',
        databaseURL: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        appId: '1:1702713223'   }, 
  firebase: {
        apiKey: '',
        authDomain: '',
        databaseURL: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        appId: '1:37840'   } };
```

I need to use environment.firebaseconfig in one component and environment.firebase in another component.

I am using angularfire for firebase connection, i have tried importing at the module level for initialization, but by defalut only one environment variable is set.

Any solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look into [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1305) solution

```
// ... do all required imports
import {
    firebaseConfigA, firebaseAppNameA,
    firebaseConfigB, firebaseAppNameB
} from "@app/env";
import { FirebaseService } from "../../services/firebase.service";

@Component({
    selector       : "page-home",
    templateUrl    : "home.html"
})
export class ScannerDemoPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Initialize 1st application
        this._firebaseService.initFirebaseApp(firebaseConfigA, firebaseAppNameA);
        let myList = this._firebaseService.getList("/path1");

        // Initialize 2nd application
        this._firebaseService.initFirebaseApp(firebaseConfigB, firebaseAppNameB);
        let myObj = this._firebaseService.getObject("/path2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, certainly helped me to fix it, using the below stackblitz,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-or2ehb

Comment: Great to know it, please upvote the answer so that someone else find it useful